# md5 Hash for SVN Dump Files

Tags: python, svn, md5

SVN dump files can have a md5 hash for copy-sources like

```
Text-copy-source-md5: 8aa166237366dd70ad4b5ebbfa0d3d58
```

How is this value calculated?

with a copy-from source of `Node-copyfrom-rev: 63`

If I do

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update('Node-copyfrom-rev: 63')
m.hexdigest()
```

I will get

```
'1af6bd9e83deb798f2e47b5fe9787619
```

instead.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: md5 is usually the contents of the file, not the file name.

Comment: This is a question about svn's files, not about programming, so it probably belongs somewhere else… but I'm not sure which site it belongs on. superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text-copy-source-md5` is a hash of the source specified by the `Node-copyfrom-rev` and `Node-copyfrom-path` lines, not the actual text of the lines used to specify the source.

So, in your case, you'd have to fetch rev 63 of the appropriate file (whatever it is) and hash that.